# Using browser-sync with node.js app

Tags: node.js, browser-sync

I have an existing node app. My Node directory structure is setup like this:

```
./
  node_modules/
  src/
    views/
      index.html
      ...
    server.js
  test/
  gulpfile.js
  package.json
```

I can successfully start my app my running `node ./src/server.js` from the root shown above. Once started, I can visit "http://localhost:3000" in the browser and see the contents of index.html like I am expecting.

I want to speed up my development and I recently learned about [browsersync](https://www.browsersync.io/). In an attempt to include it in my gulp process, I have the following:

```
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

browserSync.init({
  server: {
    baseDir: './src/',
    server: './src/server.js'
  }
});
```

When I run gulp, I see the following in the command-line:

BS] Access URLs:

```
 --------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000
    External: http://[ip address]:3000
 --------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://[ip address]:3001
 --------------------------------------
```

My browser is then opened and it attempts to load http://localhost:3000. At this point, I see the following error in the browser window:

```
Cannot GET /
```

What am I doing wrong? I can successfully visit http://localhost:3000 if I start my app using `node ./src/server.js`, however, its like its not running with BrowserSync. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can anybody help with this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You already have a node server so i think what you need is `Proxy`.
And i would also suggest you to use `nodemon` for going one step ahead in your `speed up development` thing. It will automatically restart your node development server in case of any changes. So a sample gulpfile in your case(with `nodemon`) might look like

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var reload = browserSync.reload;
var nodemon = require('gulp-nodemon');


gulp.task('browser-sync', ['nodemon'], function() {
    browserSync.init(null, {
        proxy: "http://localhost:3700", // port of node server
    });
});

gulp.task('default', ['browser-sync'], function () {
    gulp.watch(["./src/views/*.html"], reload);
});

gulp.task('nodemon', function (cb) {
    var callbackCalled = false;
    return nodemon({script: './src/server.js'}).on('start', function () {
        if (!callbackCalled) {
            callbackCalled = true;
            cb();
        }
    });
});
```

~

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to use the built-in server if you have your own in `./src/server.js` ?

Check [this](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/#option-server), What **server** in browsersync does is create a static server for basic HTML/JS/CSS websites, so you might need to use the **proxy** feature as shown [here](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/#option-proxy).
This means that you need to run your server as normally and wrap it up in the proxy.

Comment: I have my own server. However, I'm trying to figure out how to enable the live reload capabilities so that the browser automatically refreshes while I'm developing my app.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `express` generator default folder structure with the start script in `bin\www`, and using the `ejs` template, this is how i modified my `gulpfile.js` :

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var reload = browserSync.reload;
var nodemon = require('gulp-nodemon');


gulp.task('browser-sync', ['nodemon'], function() {
    browserSync.init(null, {
        proxy: "http://localhost:8000", // port of node server
    });
});

gulp.task('default', ['browser-sync'], function () {
    gulp.watch(["./views/*.ejs"], reload);
});

gulp.task('nodemon', function (cb) {
    var callbackCalled = false;
    return nodemon({
        script: './bin/www', 
        env: {
        PORT: 8000
    }}).on('start', function () {
        if (!callbackCalled) {
            callbackCalled = true;
            cb();
        }
    });
});
```

Notice that am watching for any files that end in `.ejs`. I also got a problem when using `nodemon` with the port in use, so i added an env to pass the port as 8000, 
`env: { PORT: 8000 }`

Answer (score 0):

Since the tag `grunt` is missing from the question, here's a solution that works using only NPM (`package.json`):

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "browser-sync start --serveStatic 'src' --serveStatic 'node_modules' --files 'src'"
 }
```

Now all the `<script>` src attributes can be relative:

```
<script src="/stats-js/build/stats.min.js"></script>
```